# How do I add my objects to an array on form submit using JSON and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

How can I add objects that I have already returned from my database to an array on form submit? I am retrieving all of my players from my database like so,

```
$players = Player::all();
```

and outputting them like this:

```
<form>

@foreach($players as $player)

<ul>

    <li>

    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $player->id }}">
    {{ $player->fn }} {{ $player->ln }}

    </li>

</ul>

@endforeach

<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

This is what I consider my "player pool", where all players are loaded and available to be "checked" in. I am simply trying to have two sections on this page, one that has the player pool, and one that shows the selected players from the players pool. When a player is checked in they are added to the "players in game" section below the "player pool", and will be part of a new form that can again be submitted, but to the database instead of the same just to the page. How would I achieve this with JSON and PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure how you want to use JSON for this, but you probably want to use the player ID as the value for the checkbox rather than the name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="player_ids[]" value="{{ $player->id }}">
```

Then you will have an array of player IDs in `$_GET['player_ids']` (or `$_POST['player_ids']` if this ends up being a POST form.)

Comment: Awesome! This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I had planned to use JSON and AJAX to load the players from the pool without refreshing the page, but I have decided instead to post the data to a different page to be included on the second form.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to give you form a class so you can begin building a jQuery function to select the players as a checkboxes within the form become checked.

Say,

```
<form class="player_form">
</form>
```

With the form structure you propose in your question, the firstname and lastname (I am assuming) are just echoes next to the box. If you are wanting submit these in a later form you will need to have these as input fields, like your checkbox:

```
<input type="text" name="player_name" value="{{$player=>fname}}" />
```

I think you want to move all of the information within a li element if the checkbox within that li is checked. To do this, you can add a listener to the checbox using [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/). You can also use [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) but this won't listen on the event where the box is checked by keyboard!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".player_form :checkbox").change( function() {
    var player = $(this).closest("li");

   //Now add this point into your new form

   $(".my_submit_form").append(player);
)}
});
```

The [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function will traverse up the dom and find the closest li element and then append this data to your new form.

I would suggest you reconsider your form naming convention. As you have it you will be submitting a unique name with every checkbox, I don't think this is what you mean to say.

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="player_id[]" value="{{$player->id}}" />
<input type="text" name="player_fname[]" value="{{$player=>fname}}" />
<input type="text" name="player_lname[]" value="{{$player=lname}}" />
</li>
```

Would be something like what you want, for form handling. Don't forget the names must be submitted as an array (i.e player_id[]) because you will be submitting multiple players within a form!